# How to mock a dependency of a class which is instantiated on runtime

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class X, which is instantiated runtime from my code.

```
Class X {
    @Autowired
    Map xyz;

   //Other code
}
```

Now I have some code that instantiates it:

```
Class Y {
  public void someMethod() {
   X object = new X();
   object.doSomething();
}
```

Now, I am writing tests for class Y, which in turn instantiates class X. 
Is there a way I can Mock the autowired map(in X)?

Comment: AFAIK the `@Autowire` will not work when you call `new X()` (not only in tests but also in production).

Comment: Why wouldn't it work though? There is a bean created with this name..